# How to know which object need to be used for particular method in Anguilla Project for Tridion 2011 sp1?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

In the process of implementing a GUI Extension I required some commands Example: to know the currently focused field, current field value in JavaScript file. For those in Anguilla Project documentation we can find some methods but what are the appropriate objects to be used to call those methods? How to know about them?  How to keep track of the "focusmove" event in JavaScript file? Please help me. Thanks in advance. Early response is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I think the only *real* way currently is to ask for it unfortunately.

If you ask some real questions here, you may get real answers. Vague questions like this one will get vague answers like this one.

If you are trying to get the current value of the fields you may want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463406/get-a-fields-current-value-in-component-editor-tridion-2011-sp1). For other, more specific questions about Anguilla, please post them.

Comment: How to use the function "getFieldXml()" which is located in the documentation path: "GUI Extension API_tcm89-20010\Documentation\Tridion.Controls.FieldDesigner.EmbeddedSchemaField.html". How to get the Complete set of Embedded schema field values? Which command to be used ? Thanks in advance. Please help in this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the controls are documented. API Documentation is distributed together with the CME installer. I believe, there is special option in the installer for it.

Comment: It's a separate download from SDL Tridion World. https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/GUI%20Extension%20API_tcm89-20010.zip (remember: you need to log on to SDL Tridion World **before** accessing that link).